# How to return value from for loop in .then function in Cypress

Tags: api, callback, cypress, cypress-custom-commands

```js
//command.ts
Cypress.Commands.add("getRunID"): any => {
return cy.getData().then((response: any) => {     
      var JsonResponse: any = response.body;
      var id: any = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < JsonResponse.Items.length; i++) {
        id[i] = JsonResponse.Items[i].Id;
      }
    
      var runID: any;
//looping through previous response id and passing that into URL(each id i am checking response , where the response is not null,I will get the runID)
      for (var i = 0; i < id.length; i++) {     
        let url = "**url+id[i]**"      
        cy.request({
          method: "Get",
          url: url,
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            accept: "application/json",
          },
        }).then((response) => {
          
          if (response.body.Items.length !== 0) {  //condition for fetching runID 
            var runId = response.body.Items[0].Id;
            return runId;  **//not returning value**         
          }
        });
      } //for loop end
 });
}

//Test.ts -test file
cy.getRunID().then((result)=>{console.log(result)})
```

I want to return `runId` from method `getRunID` (which is a command in command.ts).

I think the problem is `runId` is set inside the `if` loop and I am not able to return this id as the for loop keeps running.

As a consequence a `null` id is returned. How can i solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't mix asynchronous commands `cy.request()` and synchronous loops, because the code needs to wait for requests to finish.

So, at the end make a `cy.then()` call to do the wait for all prior `cy.request()`, then do a `cy.wrap()` to make `runId` the result of the command.

```js
Cypress.Commands.add("getRunID") => {
    ...

  } //for loop end
  cy.then(() => {   <-- now requests are finished
    cy.wrap(runId)  <-- set the command result
  })
})
```

Comment: Thank you this worked using wrap outside for loop